# How do I uninstall Postgres?

Tags: 10.10, postgresql

How can I completely uninstall postgres and reinstall it. I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql postgresql-doc postgresql-common
```

But I got:

```
Package postgresql is not installed, so not removed
Package postgresql-doc is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-client-8.4 : Depends: postgresql-client-common (>= 104~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: What is the result of the command `apt-get -f install`?

Comment: The following NEW packages will be installed:
  postgresql-client-common

Comment: That seemed to fix my install

Comment: So is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes it is solved

Answer (score 2):

I didn't need to reinstall, I just simply needed to `apt-get -f install` to install the client-common tools.